# Lock/Fix Windows XP Screen Resolution

Tags: windows, windows-xp, edid

I am looking for a method to lock the screen resolution of a Windows XP machine. The resolution would be device independent meaning the system should ignore any EDID information that will be passed by any monitor.

Example: Windows XP resolution set to 1280x1024@60Hz no matter what monitor is attached this is the default output. If the EDID reports supporting higher resolutions, Windows XP should ignore this information and continue to display at 1280x1024.

I suppose I could run a script on boot that writes the resolution into the registry, but that seems a bit kludgy to me. Is there a EDID ignore/disable etc Registry key?